# Create stacked pandas series from series with list elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with elements as list:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([ ['United States of America'],['China', 'Hong Kong'], []])
print(s)

0    [United States of America]
1            [China, Hong Kong]
2                            []
```

How to get a series like the following:

```
0 United States of America
1 China
1 Hong Kong
```

I am not sure about what happens to 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following options all return Series. Create a new frame and listify.

```
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist()).stack()

0  0    United States of America
1  0                       China
   1                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

To reset the index, use

```
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

To convert to DataFrame, call `to_frame()`

```
pd.DataFrame(s.tolist()).stack().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('countries')

                  countries
0  United States of America
1                     China
2                 Hong Kong
```

---

If you're trying to code golf, use

```
sum(s, [])
# ['United States of America', 'China', 'Hong Kong']

pd.Series(sum(s, []))

0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

Or even,

```
pd.Series(np.sum(s))

0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

However, like most other operations involving sums of lists operations, this is bad in terms of performance (list concatenation operations are inefficient).

---

Faster operations are possible using chaining with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(s)))

0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

```
pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(s)), columns=['countries'])

                  countries
0  United States of America
1                     China
2                 Hong Kong
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist())
print(df[0].fillna(df[1].dropna().item()))
```

Output:

```
0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that is list

```
pd.Series(s.sum())
Out[103]: 
0    United States of America
1                       China
2                   Hong Kong
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler and probably way less computationally expensive to do that through pandas function `explode`. See at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). In your case, the answer would be:

```
s.explode()
```

Simple as it is! In a case with more columns you can specify which one you would like to "explode" by adding the name of it in literals, for example `s.explode('country')`.